# How can I write these chemical reactions with structures?

Tags: chemistry

For my bachelor thesis, I want to show these reactions but I have no clue how I can put them nicely in LaTex.[image: Reactions in my Thesis]

Comment: the overleaf tag isn't necessary because this has nothing to do with overleaf per se.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\definesubmol{ro}{\textcolor{red}{O}}
\definesubmol{gme}{
    \textcolor{gray}{C}|\textcolor{gray}{H}_{\textcolor{gray}{3}}
}
\definesubmol{gmer}{
    \textcolor{gray}{H}_{\textcolor{gray}{3}}|{\textcolor{gray}{C}}
}
\begin{document}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{(-[:-42]*5(=-=(-!{gme})-!{ro}-))(-[:78]*5(=-=-!{ro}-))(-[:198]*5(-!{ro}-(-!{gmer})=-=))}
    \arrow[,,,,red]
    \chemfig[angle increment=30]{(-[1]-[3]-[1]!{gme})-[9](-[7]-[5]-[7]-[5]-[7]!{gmer})-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1]!{gme}}
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Hi and welcome among us.

You are asking if you can draw anything with LaTeX. Yes, you can with the [`tikz`](https://tikz.dev/) package.

There are also `chemfig` and `chemmacros` packages. Here are some [examples of chemistry](https://latex.net/drawing-chemical-reaction-schemes/).

I have to warn you that Tikz's learning curve is steep as hell. It also makes *nearly anything* possible to plot.